# Can I deploy ios app to iphone 5s real mobile with xcode13?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm beginner in ios developer.
I want to run app or deploy app with real mobile (iphone 5s) with xcode 13 for test because my MacBook too slow when run on emulator.

Comment: iPhone 5s can run iOS 12 and xCode 13 can debug iOS 9 so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, connect your device to the mac and select it as a run target in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can however you need to make sure the iphone5s is updated to the latest iOS version or else it will create an error on deploying